# jstack -l vs. systemd service with PrivateTmp set

Tags: java, jvm, systemd, jstack

I run a Tomcat instance as a `systemd` service. For increased security, I've set [`PrivateTmp=true`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#PrivateTmp=).

The manual (see link above) says:

> This is useful to secure access to temporary files of the process, but makes sharing between processes via /tmp/ or /var/tmp/ impossible.

Can I still use `jstack` from the OpenJDK distribution to get a thread dump in any way?

Invoking it the usual way yields the following error message

> [PID]: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
> The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding

I guess this is due to the following files / socket

```
/tmp/hsperfdata_*
/tmp/.java_pid*
```

being stored under the Tomcat service private tmp sub folder created by systemd dynamically, e.g. `/tmp/systemd-private-12c09ea37f57037c11e53e634171a9bb-mytomcat.service-2Hq3RF/`:

Can I manually point `jstack` to the correct tmp sub directory? Maybe by some environment variable or command line parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure what "the usual way" is for you, but you just need the pid of the JVM.

Comment: There is no way to change the socket path in JDK 8. AFAIK, the problem is solved in JDK 11 - jstack will automatically find the right directory. Alternatively, try [jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) - a tiny utility that does not depend on JDK and solves exactly this kind of issues.

Comment: @passer-by Yes, that's what I tried but it returns the quoted error message with [PID] being a placeholder for the actual PID. It seems this approach does not work due to the `/tmp/.java_pid****` socket being under the systemd privatetmp folder dynamically generated by systemd for the service run.